# Wireless shared web cam (not using iPhone or iPad....)

Tags: macos, wifi, webcam

In our team we have stand up meetings with a TV on the wall displaying the Google/Zoom meet with the people that are working remote for te day.

The role of hosting the meeting is circulating, so different people share their screen to the TV (works great), but using the webcam on the wall works not so smooth, since it is wired.

What product enables a wireless experience where anyone in room - on the same - network OFC - can "claim" a webcam and use it for the meeting experience.

We do not want to run around and place your iPhone in a stand, or, fetch a cable to plug into the computer.

There must be a solution? USB over IP is out of te question, it is simply overcomplicated to use and works so-so.